# JAXB - Java code to get the value of XML Node

Tags: xml, jaxb

I'm new to XML parsing and JAXB. I have the following sample XML and I'm using JAXB for parsing it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<RootResponse>
 <AggrValue columnname="a">.00826</AggrValue> 
 <AggrValue columnname="b">12345</AggrValue> 
 <AggrValue columnname="c">1128</AggrValue> 
 <AggrValue columnname="d">1776</AggrValue> 
 <AggrValue columnname="e">17.58833</AggrValue> 
 <AggrValue columnname="f">1.03869</AggrValue> 
 <AggrValue columnname="g">133332</AggrValue> 
</RootResponse>
```

And my RootResponse class looks like :

```
public class RootResponse
{
....
@XmlElement(name="AggrValue")
private List<AggrValue> AggrValue ;    
....         
}
```

The AggrValue class is :

```
public class AggrValue
{
  @XmlAttribute(name="columnname")
  private String columnName;
  /* setters and getters */
}
```

I'm able to get the column names (a,b,c, etc.). But I need to get the value(12345,1.03869 etc.)  for each column name. Can anybody please provide me a solution ?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for reading those values?

Comment: I got the answer for it. I have added another attribute in my AggrValue class with @XmlValue: 
@XmlValue(name="columnvalue")
  private String columnValue; This gave me the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added another attribute in my AggrValue class with @XmlValue:

```
@XmlValue(name="columnvalue") private String columnValue;
```

This gave me the value.